# Unity. Is this a good realization of jumping mechanics?

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace Jumping
{
    public class JumpingMechanics : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private Transform TransformWhichJumps;
        [SerializeField] private AnimationCurve AnimationCurveWhichDescribesJumpingTrajectory;
        public bool ShouldThisCharacterJumpNow { get; set; }
        private bool _IsJumping = false;
        private Vector3 _PositionBeforeJumping;
        private float _CurrentTimeOfTheJumping = 0;
        private float _DurationOfOneJumping;

        private float GetDurationOfTheJumping()
        {
            return AnimationCurveWhichDescribesJumpingTrajectory[AnimationCurveWhichDescribesJumpingTrajectory.length - 1].time;
        }

        public void Jump()
        {
            if (_IsJumping == false)
            {
                _IsJumping = true;
                _CurrentTimeOfTheJumping = 0;
                _PositionBeforeJumping = TransformWhichJumps.transform.position;
                _DurationOfOneJumping = GetDurationOfTheJumping();
            }
        }

        private void FixedUpdate()
        {
            if (_IsJumping)
            {
                _IsJumping = (_CurrentTimeOfTheJumping < _DurationOfOneJumping);
                TransformWhichJumps.transform.position = _PositionBeforeJumping + new Vector3(0, AnimationCurveWhichDescribesJumpingTrajectory.Evaluate(_CurrentTimeOfTheJumping), 0);
                _CurrentTimeOfTheJumping += Time.fixedDeltaTime;
            }
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            if (ShouldThisCharacterJumpNow)
            {
                Jump();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Another script:

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace Jumping
{
    public class JumpingReciever : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private JumpingMechanics ObjectWithJumpingMechanics;
        [SerializeField] private CatalogOfTheKeysInInputManager KeysInInputManager;

        private void Update()
        {
            ObjectWithJumpingMechanics.ShouldThisCharacterJumpNow = Input.GetKeyDown(KeysInInputManager.SpaceKey);
        }
    }
}
```

The third script:

```
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "CatalogOfTheKeysInInputManager", menuName = "ScriptableObjects/CatalogOfTheKeysInInputManager")]
public class CatalogOfTheKeysInInputManager : ScriptableObject
{
    public string SpaceKey;
}
```

I have written a system which lets jump independently of the characters (an enemy can jump as well as a character, maybe with another Reciever but with the same JumpingMechanics class). AnimationCurve lets get the place where our jumping character was in any time. I would like to learn something new. What are the cons of this system?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that I don't know Unity so hopefully, someone else will be along to review that specific part but I just wanted to highlight that your naming is pretty verbose. It's a good idea to be descriptive but you also don't want names that take up half the space of a line.

Some examples:

- `CatalogOfTheKeysInInputManager` could be `InputManagerKeys`
- `AnimationCurveWhichDescribesJumpingTrajectory` could be `JumpAnimationCurve`
- `TransformWhichJumps` could be `JumpTransform`
- `ShouldThisCharacterJumpNow` could be `ShouldJump`
- `GetDurationOfTheJumping` could be `GetJumpDuration`